# Cannot find class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0"> 
<display-name>EST</display-name>
<description>EST Portal</description>


<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
<param-name>context ConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value> 
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 


<servlet>
<servlet-name>RptDownload</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.est.utils.RptDownload</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>InvView</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.est.utils.InvView</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>InvView</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/InvView</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RptDownload</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/RptDownload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/pages/commonerror.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<error-code>403</error-code>
<location>/pages/commonerror.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type> 
<location>/pages/commonerror.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<context-param>
<param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
<listener-class>com.est.filter.CustomHttpSessionListener</listener-class> 
</listener>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
<listener-class>com.est.web.CleanUpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<mvc: annotation-driven /> 

<context: annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.est.asg" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.est.utils" />

<cache:annotation-driven key-generator="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator" />
<beans:bean id="enhanced DefaultKeyGenerator" class="com.est.cache.interceptor.EnhancedDefaultKeyGenerator" />
<beans:bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache" />
<beans:bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:shared="true" />


<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
<property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</beans:bean> 
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.Request MappingHandlerMapping" />


<beans:bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> 
<property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/pages/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
<!-- <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" /> -->
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resource Configuration -->

<- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/*** location="/resources/" />--> 
<resources mapping="/resources/*** location="/resources/" />

<!-- Datasource Configuration --> 
<beans:bean id="estjdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"> 
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
<property name="jndiName">
<value>jdbc/ds</value>
</property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" scope="singleton"> 
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
</beans:bean>

<task:executor id="Executor" pool-size="1" /> 
<task:scheduler id="Scheduler" pool-size="1" /> 
<task:annotation-driven executor="Executor" scheduler="Scheduler" />
</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http pattern="/resource/**" security="none" />
<http entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"> 
<intercept-url pattern="/web/**" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring security_check" access="isAnonymous()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/web/j_spring security_check" access="isAnonymous()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER_ADMINISTRATION', 'IT_SUPPORT')" />
<logout success-handler-ref="CustomLogoutHandler" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
<access-denied-handler error-page="/web/Default.html" /> 

<custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" /> 
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter"/> 
<custom-filter position="LAST" ref="appFilter" />
<session-management session-authentication strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/web/Auth.html" /> 
</http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>
    <beans:bean id="CustomLogoutHandler" class="com.est.authentication.CustomLogoutHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="CustomAuthentication Provider" class="com.est.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.est.authentication.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/> 
    <beans:bean id="appFilter" class="com.est.filter.ApplicationFilter"/>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.est.authentication.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionexpiredUrl" value="/web/Default.html" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" /> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authentication Manager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
<beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" /> 
        <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
        </beans:bean> 
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"> 
        </beans:bean>
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        </beans:beans>
    </beans:list>
</beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:beans>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/web/Default.html" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Error message

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping": Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] for 
bean with name org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class 
[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] for bean with name
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception 
is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambdasdoGetBeanse(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent FutureTask.run(FutureTask.Java:266) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent. FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) 
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class 
[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. RequestMappingHandlerMapping] for bean with name
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. Request MappingHandlerMapping#0 defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception 
is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:670) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultlistableBeanFactory.java:420) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultlistableBeanFactory.getBeantNamesForType(DefaultlistableBeanFactory.java:384)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1182)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMappinginitHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:203).
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:129) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
...42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
at org.apache.catalina.loaderWebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
at org.apache.catalina.loaderWebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187) 
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372)
... 54 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] for 
bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0 defined in ServletContext resource I/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc-annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1388)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:670) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support. AbstractBeanFactory. 1sFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultlistableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultlistableBeanFactory.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultlistableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:311)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.detectMappedInterceptors(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:268) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:124) 
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:77) 
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:78) 
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokelware Interfaces (ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:120)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAware Processor.postProcess BeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:96) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambdasdoGetBeanse(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultlistableBeanFactory.java:760) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderlistener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:843)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187) 
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372)
... 59 more

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: 
No Spring WebApplication Initializer types detected on classpath
```

I am upgrading our application from Spring MVC version 3.x to 5.x.
I have updated the dependencies Spring version 5.0.4.RELEASE in pom.xml.
I am getting error message Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `spring-security.xml` you have the following lines:

```xml
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
<property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</beans:bean> 
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.Request MappingHandlerMapping" />
```

The class doesn't have a `useDefaultSuffixPattern` property, so it wouldn't work anyway.

The second class has a space in the name, and that's definitely wrong.

You should probably just removed those 4 lines.